# Formatting recursively using Locale in MessageFormat

Tags: java

We're using `MessageFormat` to manage translations in our application. We have a wrapper class (`TranslationWrapper`) containing the translation key and its parameters.

When displaying a translated message, it is formated with this command

```
String message = new MessageFormat( translationKey, aLocale ).format( parameters );
```

Where `translationKey` is in a format similar to "message {0} {1}", and parameters is an Object array containing the values for {0} and {1}.

Since any object may used as a parameter, we often use our `TranslationWrapper` as a parameter. This allows us to create localized Strings based on imbricaed translation keys.

For any object passed as a parameter, the `toString()` method is called. The `toString()` method of the `TranslationWrapper` automatically translate using the current user's Locale, but I would sometimes like to use another Locale.

Since I pass this different Locale to the `MessageFormat` in its constructor, I would like to know if there is a way to have a handle on the way the parameters' strings are generated in `MessageFormat` when replacing values like {0}. Instead of calling the `toString()` method on the `TranslationWrapper`, I would like to call something like:

```
toString(locale);
```

where locale is the Locale I passed in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather ugly solution but you can set current locale into thread local variable to use it inside toString method (if it is set):

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Locale> threadLocale = new ThreadLocal<Locale>();

...

public String translate(String translationKey, Locale aLocale, Object ...parameters) {

    Locale previousLocale = threadLocale.get();
    try {
        threadLocale.set(aLocale);
        return new MessageFormat( translationKey, aLocale ).format( parameters);
        ...
    } finally {
        threadLocale.set(previousLocale);
    }
}

// somewhere in toString method threadLocale.get() will return you current Locale
```

Comment: Still a lot less ugly than the workaround I had in mind. As a reference for others like me who didn't know about thread local variables, here is a declaration example : `private static final ThreadLocal<Locale> threadLocale = new ThreadLocal<Locale>();`

Comment: I will put this into the anwer